# Can i define "" (Nothing) as "0" in Throughout The WHOLE PHP Script?

Tags: php

In my script i currently use 100+ lines of code defining nothing as "0"

I.e

```
if ($var == "") {
    $var = 0;
}
```

Is there a way in PHP i can automatically define if anything is nothing set the value of it to 0?
I've tried

```
define('', '0');
```

But this hasn't worked

Background:

These "empty" values are being imported from lots of different types of APIs, if the users analytics do not exist, the values are set to "". When displaying this in a graph/chart/table it causes errors and breaking.

Without having the set every variable as "0" from "" (How it's imported) - I need a quicker and more efficient method.

Here's one of the API calls:

```
// January
    $janViews = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3DMINE&start-date='.$jan.'&end-date='.$feb.'&&metrics=views%2Clikes%2CsubscribersGained%2Ccomments&access_token='.$_SESSION['authcode']);
    $jsonJan = json_decode($janViews);
    $monthlyViewsJan = $jsonJan->rows[0][0];
    $monthlyLikesJan = $jsonJan->rows[0][1];
    $monthlySubsJan = $jsonJan->rows[0][2];
    $monthlyCommentsJan = $jsonJan->rows[0][3];
```

The above code is requested 12 times (Each month). Here's the verification for each month.

```
if ($monthlyViewsJan == "") {
    $monthlyViewsJan = 0;
}
if ($monthlySubsJan == "") {
    $monthlySubsJan = 0;
}
if ($monthlyCommentsJan == "") {
    $monthlyCommentsJan = 0;
}
if ($monthlyLikesJan == "") {
    $monthlyLikesJan = 0;
}
```

Comment: my head is turning around

Comment: Why do you need to do this? How are these variables being set to empty strings in the 1st place?

Comment: Create a wrapper around your api calls, that checks the returned variables and sets them accordingly. Then all calls go through this wrapper. Without seeing the actual api call code i cant be more specific

Comment: What Steve said. Just loop all the vars inside  the response object/array and validate there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there is no way to avoid actually changing the values. Your concerns about speed are unfounded, but i suspect you real concern is the amount of additional code you will have to write. In that case i would recomend a couple of approaches.

If you dont want **any** empty strings, you can parse the returned data in one go with [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php):

```
$jsonJan = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3DMINE&start-date='.$jan.'&end-date='.$feb.'&&metrics=views%2Clikes%2CsubscribersGained%2Ccomments&access_token='.$_SESSION['authcode']));

array_walk_recursive($jsonJan, function(&item, $key){
    $item = empty($item) ? 0 : $item;
});

$monthlyViewsJan = $jsonJan->rows[0][0]; //will be value or 0
```

If you cannot do that, instead storing all you variables into an array:

```
$data=[]
$jsonJan = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3DMINE&start-date='.$jan.'&end-date='.$feb.'&&metrics=views%2Clikes%2CsubscribersGained%2Ccomments&access_token='.$_SESSION['authcode']));
$data=['monthlyViewsJan'] = $jsonJan->rows[0][0];
$data=['monthlyLikesJan'] = $jsonJan->rows[0][1];
$data=['monthlySubsJan'] = $jsonJan->rows[0][2];
$data=['monthlyCommentsJan'] = $jsonJan->rows[0][3];
//all your other api calls, storing into data

//change empty strings for 0
foreach($data as &$item)
    $item = empty($item) ? 0 : $item;
//extract data array back into individual variables
extract($data);
//test
echo $monthlyViewsJan; //outputs value or 0
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

This should work for you:

It grabs all variable in your skript! And checks them if they are empty any if so it assgin it with 0

```
<?php

    $test1 = "";
    $test2 = "";
    $test3 = "";
    $test4 = "test";

    $arr1 = get_defined_vars();

    foreach ($arr1 as $k => $v) {

        if(!is_array($arr1[$k]) && $$k == "")
            $$k = 0;
    }

    echo $test1 . "<br />";
    echo $test2 . "<br />";
    echo $test3 . "<br />";
    echo $test4 . "<br />";


?>
```

Output:

```
0
0
0
test
```

Also if you use `define();` your defining a `constant` not a `variable`!

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I still have to write this out 100s of times as validation for my different variables. I want EVERY variable that exists in my document that has a value of "" to be given a value of "0"

Comment: @Typeconor just initialize the variables at the beginning with 0 instead of ""! And no you cant say your script that all variables with value "" should be 0

Comment: Are you taking the piss? I'm not defining the variables. They're empty variables being imported via Google OAuth 2.0

Comment: @Typeconor you can assgin a value to multiple variables like this: `varA = varB = varC = 0;` If this helps you

Comment: It'd work in some scenarios, but overall would still have a large affect on the page-loading time.

Comment: @Typeconor how can this effect load times? resigning the value of a primitive has got to be one of the quickest things you can do in any language, you could do this 1,000,0000 times in miliseconds

Comment: After redefining each variable i make an AJAX request for each verification method to convert it into a JSON which i can place into a usable javascript format in my chart. (safely) 20.7 second page loading time.